# How to do a two-column lookup in excel?

Tags: excel, lookup

I would like to put in a formula in the F column on Sheet 1, that would match Columns C and D with Columns A and B of Sheet 2 and give me the value of Column C of Sheet 2.

I've tried using the formulas in the following links:

1. [Excel table lookup matching values of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543805/excel-table-lookup-matching-values-of-two-columns)
2. [Two Column Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890319/two-column-lookup)

I wasn't sure how to apply them to my situation, due to the fact that I'm an Excel noob.

[image: Sheet 1] [image: Sheet 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the value in Column C numeric? If so, try the sumifs formula:
=sumifs(Sheet2!C:C, Sheet2!A:A, C2, Sheet2!B:B, D2)

Otherwise, you need the index/match solution that are found in both links you noted.

Edit: Corrected formula

Comment: Yes, the value in C is numeric. The links at the very bottom have screenshots of the sheets. But this formula didn't work; the Top image is Sheet 1, the bottom image is Sheet 2

Comment: Sorry, there was a small error in my formula that I fixed. The screenshots also weren't showing up earlier but I see them now. If you copy that formula into F2 and drag down, it should work.

Comment: The formula works but I'm having trouble copying it to other cells, it gives me the same result each time.

Comment: Autofill down using the bottom right corner of the cell

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be best suited using vba to do this, there probably is a way to do it on the worksheet, but why put yourself through that pain when you can use some fairly simple vba code to do the exact same thing. An example is as follows.

```
Dim Rows1 as Long
Dim Rows2 as Long
Dim Sheet1Arr() as Variant
Dim Sheet2Arr() as Variant
Rows1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Rows2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim Sheet1Arr(1 to Rows1, 1 to 2)
ReDim Sheet2Arr(1 to Rows2, 1 to 2)
    For j = 1 to Rows1
        If Sheet1Arr(j, 1) = Sheet2Arr(j, 1) and Sheet1Arr(j, 2) = Sheet2Arr(j, 2) Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j) = Sheet2Arr(j , 2)
        End If
    Next j
```

Keep in mind I made **A LOT** of assumptions on what you are trying to do because your question wasn't very specific.

Comment: Let me ask you the reverse question: Why put yourself through writing (non-volatile) VBA code when you can use a formula instead?

Comment: I feel like using VBA is cleaner, more elegant. More of a personal preference really. If you are new to excel using VBA to solve simple problems will help you learn the language. Other than that I got nothing.

Comment: Fair enough I suppose, sorry if I came across as rude or snarky.  I just have a stigma against using VBA I suppose........(when a formula is possible that is)

Comment: It appears we just have opposing life philosophies.